# Trouble with Spyder: Launch Application in one click

Tags: python, interpreter, launch, spyder

I'm new with python and not familiar with spyder.

When I start spyder and run a simple program the first time, it was started with an iPhython-Interpreter.
The program was running. But when I tried to run it a second time it resulted in an error.

I cannot give you the error message, because the ipython interpreter is disappeared somehow. Even the selection in the "Interpreters" menue.
I don't know why.

How ever, when I run it with the python interpreter it is running more then one time.
But when I wanna start my program I have to start the python interpreter first and then I can start my program.

Is there no one click solution?
Because it is a bit annoying. I forget to start the interpreter first, almost every time.

Thank you very much
Fabian